# Error while installing an application

Tags: synaptic

So i have installed synaptic package manager.. via it, i have checked once libopencv-highgui-dev and applied complete removal.. after that i installed it... now everytime i try to install an application e.g Format Junkie

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:format-junkie-team/release && sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install formatjunkie
```

in the command install format junkie it gives me that error everytime:

```
     sudo apt-get install formatjunkie
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libopencv-features2d-dev : Depends: libopencv-highgui-dev (= 2.3.1-11ubuntu2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

What should i do?
And 2nd what did i did wrong so it won't happen another time?

output of `lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.  
Distributor ID: Ubuntu   
Description:    Ubuntu 12.10  
Release:    12.10  
Codename:   quantal
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `lsb_release -a` to the question (not a screenshot, just copy/paste).

Comment: Added in the description

Comment: So, why was it necessary to remove `libopencv-highgui-dev` and then reinstall it? Can you double check it is installed.

Comment: I was compiling my project and it gave me an error for a missing lib.. so installed it but it wasn't this one the problem... so i complete removed it.. and then i installed libopencv-dev (which has libopencv-highgui-dev in it)..  yes it is installed: http://i.imgur.com/YnpJt.png

Comment: When quoting errors from the terminal, it is preferred to copy-paste instead of screenshots since it is easier to read and interpret for us.\

Comment: Won't happen next time, edited description!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open /var/log/dist-upgrade/apt.log

identify Broken packages , open terminal and execute following commands.

First Remove that broken packages completely (remove  if any other remain)

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libopencv-highgui-dev
```

System Update and upgrade packages

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Fix Dependency using this command

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Remove unnecessary packages

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Comment: folder dist-upgrade is empty..  sudo apt-get --purge libopencv-highgui-dev will give me E: Invalid operation libopencv-highgui-dev

Comment: Try the now-changed command in the answer, see if that works, @Bong.Da.City

Comment: With your edit i can now install format junkie :)

Comment: Patel: the `--purge` argument requires the `remove` directive first.  Just a note for future reference ;)

Comment: ooo and what if i want to have these libs installed and format junkie? ( as i said i want the libs so i can compile a programm called wallch )... see what it shows me when i try to install libopencv-dev (http://i.imgur.com/hREGE.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this: `apt-get install formatjunkie libopencv-highgui-dev=2.3.1-11ubuntu2 libopencv-features2d-dev`

That should force it (don't forget sudo!) to try and get the version it requires.

If not, I'll take a look at that package, it may just be broken in the PPA (I'm one of the uploaders to that PPA, if you read the uploader entries :P)

Comment: O you are the one that maked our ppa? :) I am the other developer of format-junkie.. Anywho i solved my problem with the answer of K.K Patel that u edited :) Could u tell me what i did wrong and all this happened? Should i apply removal and not complete removal? What is the difference?

Comment: The issue was likely a bug in the system, the command that Patel gave omitted the 'remove' command which is necessary (the --purge argument requires the remove command).  The other issue is the system wasn't installing the right version (I've seen that happen before).  And yes, I upload the packages to the PPA whenever the other dev pushes a code change to the bzr branches on Launchpad. (I'm working on porting to Raring now)

Comment: Anyone? and what if i want to have these libs installed and format junkie? ( as i said i want the libs so i can compile a programm called wallch )... see what it shows me when i try to install libopencv-dev (http://i.imgur.com/hREGE.png)... and if install it and it removes format junkie.. then when i try to install format junkie it shows me the same error as my 1st post...

Comment: You seem to be wanting to install something that is incompatible.  The package installs the bare essentials.  If you want to use custom libs outside those defined in the packaging, you'll need to build formatjunkie from source.  I can't make packages work with each other when they're incompatible.  The libs you specify are marked as "Incompatible" with the libs installed by the package.  You and I should communicate on IRC or a chat channel in here, or email, to discuss this...

Comment: @Bong.Da.City https://bugs.launchpad.net/format-junkie/+bug/1074575  <-- Go to that bug, and read up.  Also, you should subscribe to the bugs on the bugtracker there on launchpad.